# Property of E.coli harboring F element

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, bacteriology, molecular-genetics, virus

From *Genetics by Ursula Goodenough*

> E.coli harboring an F element are endowed with a number of phenotypic
>   traits :
>
> 1.They are sensitive to infection by ssRNA phages and certain ssDNA phages.
>
> 2.They resist the growth of female specific phages as T3 and T7.

What is the molecular mechanism behind this sensitivity and resistance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Some bacteriophages adsorb on the pili. So the individuals carrying the F-element will be susceptible to these.
2. F-plasmid encoded membrane protein PifA is responsible for the T7 resistance [See [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0042682204003824)]. The exact mechanism is not known

*If you see the list of references in the textbook chapter you will be able to trace the reference for a certain quoted fact*